# entity to linq where clause

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using entity to linq

Please find my  linq query -

```
 Using lcntxRT60Entities As New RT60Entities(EntityConnection)

            Dim lstrDocumentWhereClause As String
            lstrDocumentWhereClause = astrDocumentWhereClause & " AND it.TransactionType = " + aintTransactionType.ToString + " AND it.VoidIndicator = 0"
            lstrDocumentWhereClause = lstrDocumentWhereClause & " AND it.RtRouteDetails.RouteNumber = " + aintRouteNumber.ToString

            If adatFromDate.ToString IsNot Nothing And adatToDate.ToString IsNot Nothing Then
                adatToDate = adatToDate.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59)
                lstrDocumentWhereClause = lstrDocumentWhereClause & " AND (it.TransactionDateTime BETWEEN DATETIME'" & Convert.ToDateTime(adatFromDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") & "' AND DATETIME'" & Convert.ToDateTime(adatToDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "')"
            End If

            Dim Documents = From CTH In lcntxRT60Entities.RtCstTrnHeader.Where(lstrDocumentWhereClause) _
                            Join C In lcntxRT60Entities.RtCustomer.Where(astrCustomerWhereClause) On CTH.RtCustomer.CustomerID Equals C.CustomerID _
                            Select CTH, C _
                            Order By CTH.RouteKey, CTH.VisitKey, CTH.TransactionKey

            Dim DocumentDetails = From Document In Documents.ToList _
                                  Select Document.CTH

            Return DocumentDetails.Skip(aintStartRow).Take(aintPageSize).ToList
```

i have problem with my where clause -

```
  lstrFilterCriteria = "it.DocumentPrefix + it.DocumentNumber LIKE '" & lstrValue.ToString().Trim() & "'"
```

this throw conversion error .

If i use this

```
lstrFilterCriteria = "it.DocumentPrefix+SqlFunctions.StringConvert((integer)it.DocumentNumber) LIKE '" & lstrValue.ToString().Trim() & "'"
```

its throw syntax error .

how to convert  concatenate this two column . 
Document prefix is string and document number is integer . 
Please suggest .
Thnaks

Comment: You appear to be confusing strings with Linq/Lamba expressions?

Comment: @DavidG- sorry i didnt got you , actualy i puting where clause where i m concatenating two column . in sql it will be like that                                        select * from RtCstTrnHeader where 
DocumentPrefix + CONVERT(nvarchar, DocumentNumber) like 'as%'

Comment: First, `StringConvert` is not available for `int`. It take a nullable double or a nullable decimal. I don't know the type of DocumentNumber, if it's an int, you should cast it to a double or a decimal. Then, I'm not sure that using `(integer)variableName` is the way to cast in vb, is it ?

Comment: ok i changed to vb  lstrFilterCriteria = "it.DocumentPrefix+SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double(it.DocumentNumber)) LIKE '" & lstrValue.ToString().Trim() & "'" so syntax error gone but  its not recognize SqlFunctions.StringConvert

Comment: if i simplify the question so it will be how to write this query  select * from RtCstTrnHeader where 
DocumentPrefix + CONVERT(nvarchar, DocumentNumber) like 'as%' into LINQ to Entities

Comment: in c# it would be`+ SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)it.DocumentNumber) ...`, but shouldn't you use something like `DirectCast` in vb ?

Comment: If I where you, I would really try a "non dynamic" working version first...

Answer (score 0):

```
Using lcntxRT60Entities As New RT60Entities(EntityConnection)
Dim query=lcntxRT60Entities.RtCstTrnHeader
    .Where(t=>t.TransactionType==aintTransactionType)
    .Where(t=>t.VoidIndicator==0)

If adatFromDate.ToString IsNot Nothing And adatToDate.ToString IsNot Nothing Then
  adatToDate = adatToDate.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59)
  query=query.Where(t=>t.TransactionDateTime>adatFromDate && t.TransactionDateTime<adatToDate);
End If

query=query
  .OrderBy(t=>t.RouteKey)
  .ThenBy(t=>t.Visitkey)
  .ThenBy(t=>t.TransactionKey)

Return query.Skip(aintStartRow).ToList
```

You will have to add in your own parameters for whatever astrDocumentWhereClause and astrCustomerWhereClause may contain before this as you didn't supply it in your example code.